# Nolearn DBM fails to train

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to train a dbm using nolearn, but form some reason it is failing.
Every train example is a vector of 1.0's, same for Test. When I was using the "real" input I was getting the same error.

The training code is almost identical to the one for training on MNIST in the nolearn documation.

```
# import the necessary packages
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import datasets
from nolearn.dbn import DBN

# scale the data to the range [0, 1] and then construct the training
# and testing splits
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split( features , targets , test_size = 0.33)

print trainX.shape
print trainY.shape

dbn = DBN(
[trainX.shape[1], 80, 80, trainY.shape[1]],
learn_rates = 0.3,
learn_rate_decays = 0.9,
epochs = 10,
verbose = 1)
dbn.fit(trainX, trainY)

# compute the predictions for the test data and show a classification
# report
preds = dbn.predict(testX)
```

It fails for some reason I cannot find:

```
100%

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5324a7be4932> in <module>()
     19 epochs = 10,
     20 verbose = 1)
---> 21 dbn.fit(trainX, trainY)
     22 
     23 # compute the predictions for the test data and show a classification

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nolearn/dbn.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    388                 loss_funct,
    389                 self.verbose,
--> 390                 self.use_dropout,
    391                 )):
    392             losses_fine_tune.append(loss)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/dbn.pyc in fineTune(self, minibatchStream, epochs, mbPerEpoch, loss, progressBar, useDropout)
    207                 prog.tick()
    208             prog.done()
--> 209             yield sumErr/float(totalCases), sumLoss/float(totalCases)
    210 
    211     def totalLoss(self, minibatchStream, lossFuncts):

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

gnumpy: failed to import cudamat. Using npmat instead. No GPU will be used.
(1, 200)
(1, 125)
[DBN] fitting X.shape=(1, 200)
[DBN] layers [200, 80, 80, 125]
[DBN] Fine-tune...
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify than `trainY.shape[1]` is the same as the number of your classes.

I had this problem once before, and making sure those matched fixed it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Barranka, as I said, I had the same problem and this was the solution at least for me (one of the parameters was not the right one).

Answer (score 0):

I switched from pandas dataframes to numpy arrays to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your training dataset might be small. Just add one more argument in your DBN object, `minibatch_size=1`, by default it is `minibatch_size=64`. You can tweak further as per your requirements.
Example:

```
dbn = DBN(
    [trainX.shape[1], 300, 5],
    learn_rates = 0.3,
    learn_rate_decays = 0.9,
    epochs = 10,
    verbose = 1,
    minibatch_size=1)
```